# Build a blockchain

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, blockchain, substrate-front-end, block

I'm following substrate documentation in that build a blockchain tutorial while following the monitoring node metrics tutorial.

I got stuck while installing prometheus on my ec2 instance is there any correct method to install prometheus.

Comment: Check this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/monitor-node-metrics/

Comment: I refered the same documentation but got error